# @import not working for my "application.css.scss" file in Rails project, only works as "application.css"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, sass

so I have run into an issue with my Rails project. in my Gemfile, this is my code:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'thin'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'eco'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
   gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Here is my application.css.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I run into this error if I take the 'group :assets do' block out and instead just try to run rails w/out it:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.3/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-1.1.3/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

To get rid of that, I HAVE to use the group :assets do block. but then, once I get the rails server up and running, if '@import "bootstrap";' is in application.css.scss (because the file has .scss appended to it), I get the following error when I try to load my rails project in the browser:

```
 Showing /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/app/assets/images
  /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-2.2.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  (in /Users/Stuart/Documents/Code/Sublime/one_kingdom_design/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:13)
```

Here is the extracted source it highlights:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OneKingdomDesign</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>//this line is highlighted in the firefox browser
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Can anyone help me find what the source of this issue might be? I believe it has everything to do with the Sass gem, but I'm not sure. I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p247 if that matters.

EDIT: I've narrowed it down, it's not sass, it's compass-rails. no matter what I try, compass is trying to argue with me.

Comment: What version of Sass are you using?

Comment: 4.0.1? However I just did a few changes, and got rid of the group :assets do block and only took out the 'gem 'compass-rails'' line and the server ran and the page refreshed fine. so it HAS to be something to do with "gem 'compass-rails'"

Comment: I don't know anything about the Rails specific gems, but I do know there is a version conflict between the current stable versions of Sass and Compass.  If you have the current stable version of Sass, you need to get the edge version of Compass.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an app I'm migrating from rails 3.2 to rails 4.  I'm using ruby 1.9.3.  I'm not using compass, just bootstrap-sass.  rake assets:precompile is failing here: .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-rails-4.0.1/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:84:in `evaluate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following in my rails4 app.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem and I think I've got to the bottom of it

First of all I can explain why you get the error only when you do not include the assets group in the gemfile.  Rails 4 does not expect an assets group in there and doesn't include the gems.  That means if your basecamp gem is wrapped in the group :assets do block it doesn't get included, thus no problems precompiling but also no bootcamp files when you try to include them with @import.

Now for why the precompiling is going wrong.  I noticed that here:

http://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails

Sass-rails requires sprockets less than or equal to 2.11.0, i.e it is not compatible with version 2.11.1 which is what I was getting in my bundle.  I thought these things were supposed to be handled automatically by bundler so I've no idea what is going on there.   I suggest you look in your Gemfile.lock and check the versions that you have for sass (which is included by sass-rails) and bootstrap-sass and all the various dependencies and make sure rubygems agrees that they are compatible.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue, but updating from sass 4.0.1 solved it for me.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
```